# JRuby Heroku Gem

Tags: ssl, heroku, rubygems, openssl, jruby

Is it possible to use Heroku client with JRuby?

I have installed heroku gem successfully with all dependencies, but I can't login.

```
PS D:\Projects\myproject> heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: myname@mydomain.com
Password (typing will be hidden): mypassword

 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       write would raise (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
    Backtrace:   org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:626:in `syswrite_nonblock'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/1.9/openssl/buffering.rb:374:in `write_nonblock'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/excon-0.15.5/lib/excon/socket.rb:117:in `write'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/excon-0.15.5/lib/excon/connection.rb:223:in `request_kernel'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/excon-0.15.5/lib/excon/connection.rb:101:in `request'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-api-0.3.2/lib/heroku/api.rb:60:in `request'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-api-0.3.2/lib/heroku/api/login.rb:5:in `post_login'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/auth.rb:76:in `api_key'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/auth.rb:185:in `ask_for_credentials'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/auth.rb:217:in `ask_for_and_save_credentials'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/auth.rb:80:in `get_credentials'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/auth.rb:41:in `login'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb:22:in `login'
                 org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1667:in `__send__'
                 org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2060:in `send'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/command.rb:179:in `run'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in `start'
                 C:/JRuby/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/heroku-2.30.2/bin/heroku:16:in `(root)'
                 org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1050:in `load'
                 C:\JRuby\bin\heroku:23:in `(root)'

    Command:     heroku login
    Version:     heroku-gem/2.30.2 (java) ruby/1.9.3

PS D:\Projects\myproject>
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had the same problem with OpenSSL and JRuby (ruby 1.9.2) incompatibility.
If you just want to login, try

> JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8 heroku login

This will use the 1.8.7 version of ruby implementation of jruby which should work with OpenSSL

Edit: For windows

> set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8
>
> heroku login
>
> set JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9

Edit:

As of

> heroku-toolbelt/2.30.5 (java) ruby/1.9.2

I no longer have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Heroku recently [announced official jRuby support](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/12/13/run_jruby_on_heroku_right_now/) and there is a dedicated [help document on migrating exisiting apps to jRuby](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby).